# Custom Async Http Client in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I use https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http but I think this can be applied to an Async Task (native one)

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
       //Some debugging code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
        //here is the interesting part
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
         //Some debugging code here, show retry dialog, feedback etc. 
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
         //Some debugging code here-------

    }
});
```

I use it alot in lots of separate classes. The onStart, onFailure and onRetry are the same everywhere, just copy-paste, just the onSuccess is different.

I want to keep my code as clean as possible and to reuse what I've already written, so my question is, how do I make this custom, in a separate "file", and just reuse it. I need just the "OnSuccess" function. Thank you

#### ---------------------------------------

#### SOLUTION for GET & POST (Thanks to furkan3ayraktar)

1st file RequestListener

```
package com.classicharmony.krakenmessages.utils.AsyncHttp;
import org.apache.http.Header;
public interface RequestListener {
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response);
}
```

2nd file RequestHandler

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;


import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class RequestHandler {

    private static RequestHandler instance;

    private AsyncHttpClient client;
    private static final boolean SHOW_DEBUG_ALERT_DIALOG = true;

    private RequestHandler() {
        client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    }

    public static RequestHandler getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RequestHandler();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public void make_get_Request(final Context context, final String url, final RequestListener listener) {
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.v("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ GET ", url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                listener.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                Log.e("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ GET FAILED ", url);
                Log.e("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ GET FAILED ", e.getLocalizedMessage());

                if (DUtils.isDebuggable(context) && SHOW_DEBUG_ALERT_DIALOG) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("▒▒▒▒▒ ERROR ▒▒▒▒▒");
                    String error_msg;
                    if (errorResponse != null) {
                        try {
                            error_msg = String.valueOf(new String(errorResponse, "UTF-8"));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            error_msg = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }
                    } else {
                        error_msg = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    }

                    builder.setMessage(context.getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + error_msg)
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                Log.e("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ RETRYING ", "....." + String.valueOf(retryNo));

            }
        });
    }

    public void make_post_Request(final Context context, final StringEntity entity, final String url, final RequestListener listener) {
        client.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.v("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ POST ", url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                listener.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                Log.e("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ POST FAILED ", url);
                Log.e("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ POST FAILED ", context.getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + e.getLocalizedMessage());


                if (DUtils.isDebuggable(context) && SHOW_DEBUG_ALERT_DIALOG) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("▒▒▒▒▒ ERROR ▒▒▒▒▒");
                    String error_msg;
                    if (errorResponse != null) {
                        try {
                            error_msg = String.valueOf(new String(errorResponse, "UTF-8"));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            error_msg = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }
                    } else {
                        error_msg = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    }

                    builder.setMessage(context.getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + error_msg)
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                Log.e("▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ RETRYING ", "....." + String.valueOf(retryNo));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

3rd "utility" to show the dialog or not.

```
public static boolean isDebuggable(Context ctx) {
    boolean debuggable = false;
    X500Principal DEBUG_DN = new X500Principal("CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US");
    try {
        PackageInfo pinfo = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        Signature signatures[] = pinfo.signatures;

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        for (int i = 0; i < signatures.length; i++) {
            ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(signatures[i].toByteArray());
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(stream);
            debuggable = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().equals(DEBUG_DN);
            if (debuggable)
                break;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        //debuggable variable will remain false
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        //debuggable variable will remain false
    }
    return debuggable;
}
```

Example how to call it for POST:

```
JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
        StringEntity entity;


        try {
            jsonParams.put("from_user_id", "dan");
            jsonParams.put("to_user_id", "vili");
            jsonParams.put("message", "hello world");
            entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        RequestHandler handler = RequestHandler.getInstance();
        handler.make_post_Request(getActivity(), entity, "http://your_server/api/etc", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                try {
                    String server_response = String.valueOf(new String(response, "UTF-8"));
                    Log.v("Server response",server_response);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much...
It worked like a charm..
Thanks alot.. 
By the way it was edited in 2014..this must be old fashioned.

Please tell me if you are using anything else now or same.
Thanks again.

Comment: well.. there are newer ways... easier.... but if it works then use it. test it on couple of phones and versions and if it gets the job done leave it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create common request handler and listener. You can also create different request methods like makeRequest for each request you want, and also create different listeners. Here is a simple pattern I mostly use,

```
public class RequestHandler{

    private static RequestHandler instance;

    private AsyncHttpClient client;

    private RequestHandler(){
        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    }

    public static RequestHandler getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new RequestHandler();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // You can add more parameters if you need here.
    public void makeRequest(String url, RequestListener listener){
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
                //Some debugging code here
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                listener.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                //Some debugging code here, show retry dialog, feedback etc. 
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                 //Some debugging code here-------

            }
        });
    }
}

public interface RequestListener{
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response);
}
```

Then use as following in anywhere you want.

```
RequestHandler handler = RequestHandler.getInstance();
handler.makeRequest("http://www.google.com", new RequestListener(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // do whatever you want here.       
    }
});
```

Comment: great work. just make the listener final. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own, empty version of `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`, which doesn't implement the `onSuccess` method.

```
public abstract class OWADVLHttpResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {}

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {}
}
```

Your code would then look like:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new OWADVLHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
      ....
    }
});
```

Obviously, you can fill in some contents in the non-overrided methods in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

First you make an abstract base class that implements the behavior that is common. Something like this:

```
public abstract class AsyncHttpResponesHandlerBase implements AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
        // Some debugging code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
        //Some debugging code here, show retry dialog, feedback etc. 
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        //Some debugging code here-------
    }
}
```

Then per url you inherited from the base class and implement the `onSuccess()` method to handle the response.

```
public class GoogleGetHandler extends AsyncHttpResponesHandlerBase {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
        // do the Google specific handling
    }
}
```

And you make the HTTP request as follows:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new GoogleGetHandler());
```

So if you want to make calls to more urls, just keep making new subclasses based off of the base class so you inherit the common failure handling.